# BSON::InvalidObjectId illegal ObjectId format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I got this error after trying to insert a simple `if` condition in my controller :

```
def index
  if params[:query].present?
    @blog_posts = BlogPost.search(params[:query])
  else
    @blog_posts = BlogPost.all
  end 
end
```

Comment: I am using tire (elastic search) as a search engine. params[:query] is what I write to search of the key

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how your model is setup. As the [Tire README](https://github.com/karmi/tire) says, Mongoid is kinda funky with their IDs, you may have to define the `to_indexed_json` yourself:

```
def to_indexed_json
  self.as_json
end
```